# JavaFX - Tab will not show nor file contents when file is opened

Tags: java, file, javafx, tabs

I'm trying to create a text editor using JavaFX. I want to be able to open a file from a window into the main window as a tab. So far, I've created the necessary menu items and an option window that contains the function to open the file explorer to select a file.

When the user presses the "Choose File" button, the file explorer is opened. When a user selects a file, the "Open File" window closes. The main window (3rd image) is then left but does not contain a tab with the file contents.

Upon execution of the "openFile()" function, no errors are returned, but no tab is opened. I believe it may be an issue with trying to open the tab within the "chooseFileButton.SetOnAction()" function but cannot confirm.

Any suggestions/explanations would be much appreciated.

---

### Open File

[image]

### Open File (FileChooser)

[image]

### Output:

[image]

---

```
public class Main extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage primary) throws Exception {
    primary.setTitle("Chris' Text Editor");

    MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
    VBox vbox = new VBox(menuBar);

    /* FILE MENU */
    MenuItem openFile = new MenuItem("Open...");

    fileMenu.getItems().add(openFile);

    Pane rootPane = new Pane();

    TextArea editorTextArea = new TextArea();
    editorTextArea.setMinHeight(1000);
    editorTextArea.setMinWidth(1000);
    editorTextArea.setVisible(false);
    rootPane.getChildren().add(editorTextArea);

    TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setSide(Side.TOP);

    openFile.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {

            Label fileLabel = new Label();
            fileLabel.setText("No File selected...");

            GridPane grid = new GridPane();
            Scene contextScene = new Scene(grid, 450, 300);

            /* NEW WINDOW */
            Stage openFileWindow = new Stage();
            openFileWindow.setTitle("Open File");
            openFileWindow.setScene(contextScene);

            /* SET WINDOW MODAL */
            openFileWindow.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);

            /* SET PARENT WINDOW */
            openFileWindow.initOwner(primary);

            /* CHOOSE FILE DIRECTORY BUTTON */
            openFileWindow.setX(primary.getX() + (primary.getX() / 2));
            openFileWindow.setY(primary.getX() + (primary.getX() / 2));

            openFileWindow.show();

            /* CHOOSE FILE BUTTON */
            Button chooseFileButton = new Button();
            chooseFileButton.setText("Choose File");

            chooseFileButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                    FileChooser chooseFile = new FileChooser();
                    File selectedFile = chooseFile.showOpenDialog(openFileWindow);

                    if(selectedFile != null) {
                        String filePath = selectedFile.getPath();
                        fileLabel.setText(filePath);
                        String fileContent = openFile2(filePath);

                        /* CREATE NEW TAB */
                        Tab newTab = new Tab();
                        newTab.setContent(editorTextArea);
                        newTab.setText(filePath);
                        tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);

                        editorTextArea.setVisible(true);

                        /* POPULATE TEXT AREA WITH FILE CONTENTS */
                        editorTextArea.appendText(fileContent);

                        /* FOCUS ON TAB */
                        SingleSelectionModel<Tab> selection = tabPane.getSelectionModel();
                        selection.select(newTab);

                        openFileWindow.close();
                    }
                }
            });

            grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
            grid.setHgap(10);
            grid.setVgap(10);

            grid.add(chooseFileButton, 0, 0);
            grid.add(fileLabel, 0, 1);

        }


    });

    menuBar.getMenus().add(fileMenu);   

    Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 1000, 750);
    primary.setScene(scene);
    primary.show();
}
```

```
 public String openFile2(String filePath) {
    StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();

    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(filePath), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)){
        stream.forEach(s -> content.append(s).append("\n"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return content.toString();

 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never added your `TabPane` to the scene:

```
vbox.getChildren().add(tabPane);
```

Comment: I feel very silly. I added the 'rootPane' to the VBox, and then added the 'tabPane' to the 'rootPane'. Now the program works as I intended. Thanks very much!